# Arrange random string in a file in particular order using awk

Tags: awk

I have a requirement where I need to arrange the below input strings in the format shown for Output:

Input:

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRuIk.png)

OutPut:
[Output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPHH3.png)

So basically, wherever jvmArgs string found, it should get aligned to a single line with previous string and wherever it is not found, it should replace with any random string like "XXXXXXX", if possible through awk.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: Remove the images from external links and post them directly in the question. Also post your research efforts to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
#!/bin/gawk

BEGIN{
    jvm=1;
}
/^\[.+\]/{
    if(jvm==0){
        print "XXXXXX";
    }
    printf("%s ", $0);
    jvm=0;
}

/jvmArgs/{
    jvm=1;
    print;
}

END{
    if(jvm==0){
        print "XXXXXX";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect !!! This really works as expected.....Thanks for your quick response and solution. Really appreciate......

Comment: `printf("%s\n", $0)` = `print` and `printf("XXXXXX\n")` = `print "XXXXXX"`

Comment: Thanks for feedback